# How to sum when there are multiple tables joined

Tags: mysql

Bill has many packing lists, and packing lists can have many articles.

Bill can also have many articles (directly) - through a FK in articles.

How would I sum the article prices for a certain bill, considering that article can belong to a bill from article table, and bill can have a packing list which contains articles?

The format I would like is:

```
bill_Id; bill_articles_sum;
```

Which constructs do I need? I tried joining the articles table 2 times (once through the bill, second time through packing lists), ending up with a mess.

Any concept is welcome.

**Update:**

There are 3 tables involved:

```
- bills > packing_lists > articles
```

But, articles table also contains a FK to bills (so it can belong both to packing_lists and bills).

The issue for me is fetching a summary: invoice list + total invoice price (sum of articles).

I doubt it'll be helpful, but here's the code:

```
        SELECT cli_bill_id, b1.bit_cli_pack_list_id, b1.bit_sum_excl ,
        b2.bit_id, b2.bit_sum_excl

        FROM clients_bills 
        LEFT JOIN clients_packing_list ON (clients_packing_list.cli_pack_bill_id = clients_bills.cli_bill_id) 
        LEFT JOIN bill_items b1 ON (clients_packing_list.cli_pack_list_id = b1.bit_cli_pack_list_id )
        LEFT JOIN bill_items b2 ON (b1.bit_cli_pack_list_id is null and clients_bills.cli_bill_id = b2.bit_cli_bill_id)
        group by cli_bill_id, b1.bit_cli_pack_list_id, b2.bit_id
```

Comment: share the schema and what you tried.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your question with your table structure and some sample data and expected output.

Comment: There's too little info to know for certain, but it looks like you're trying to dynamically calculate the total bill for old bills. Since prices can change over time I'd recommend always storing the actual prices per bill as soon as the order is placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I get it, records of bill_items are the articles belonging to all bills, and a bill_item either belongs directly to a bill or implicitly through a packing list (but both cannot happen at the same time).

So, I can imagine a simple table structure like this (simplified a bit):

```
create table clients_bills (cli_bill_id int primary key);
create table clients_packing_list  (cli_pack_list_id int primary key, cli_pack_bill_id int references client_bills(cli_bill_id));
create table bill_items (bit_id int primary key, bit_cli_pack_list_id int references clients_packing_list(cli_pack_list_id), bit_cli_bill_id int references clients_bills(cli_bill_id), price int);
```

And some sample data like this:

```
insert into clients_bills values (1);
insert into clients_bills values (2);

insert into clients_packing_list values(1, 1);
insert into clients_packing_list values(2, 1);

-- bill_items of bill 1
insert into bill_items values (1,1,null,1);
insert into bill_items values (2,1,null,1);
insert into bill_items values (3,2,null,1);
insert into bill_items values (4,null,1,1);
-- this would be invalid: insert into bill_items values (6,2,1,1);
-- bill_items of bill 2
insert into bill_items values (5,null,2,1);
```

To get what you need, I'd change the logic of your original query, and try to determine for each record in `bill_items` its corresponding record in `clients_bills`. This is a simple join:

```
SELECT bi.bit_id, COALESCE(cpl.cli_pack_bill_id, bi.bit_cli_bill_id) AS bill_id
FROM bill_items bi
LEFT JOIN clients_packing_list cpl ON (bi.bit_cli_pack_list_id = cpl.cli_pack_list_id)
```

Once you have that, you can simply get the sum of prices with a group by:

```
SELECT COALESCE(cpl.cli_pack_bill_id, bi.bit_cli_bill_id) AS bill_id, SUM(bi.price)
FROM bill_items bi
LEFT JOIN clients_packing_list cpl ON (bi.bit_cli_pack_list_id = cpl.cli_pack_list_id)
GROUP BY COALESCE(cpl.cli_pack_bill_id, bi.bit_cli_bill_id);
```

Note, it works only if you require that a record of clients_bills has at least one corresponding record in bill_items. If it's not a requirement, and empty bills are allowed, the following should solve it:

```
SELECT cb.cli_bill_id, SUM(bi.price)
FROM bill_items bi
LEFT JOIN clients_packing_list cpl ON (bi.bit_cli_pack_list_id = cpl.cli_pack_list_id)
RIGHT JOIN clients_bills cb ON (cpl.cli_pack_bill_id = cb.cli_bill_id
  OR bi.bit_cli_bill_id = cb.cli_bill_id)
GROUP BY cb.cli_bill_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that aricle can be related to packing_list or bill directly(through FK)

```
    SELECT 
    DISTINCT(a.article_id)
    FROM articles a 
    WHERE (a.bill IS NOT NULL and a.bill_id = __BILL_ID__) or (a.packing_list_id IN(
        SELECT pl.id from packing_list where pl.bill_id = __BILL_ID__
        ));

        SELECT 
   __BILL_ID__ as bill_id, 
SUM(a.price)  as bill_price_sum  FROM articles a WHERE a.id IN( __ABOVE_SELECT__ );
```

Making it as simple as possible, assuming you want the sum for one bill at a time. You need to replace **BILL_ID** with proper value.

Comment: And if I want a list of all bills and their sums? That's what I actually need. I'm guessing Ill need to modify your query with joins then?

Comment: you would then do select b.id, ( the second select ) as price fro bill but instead of __BILL_ID__ you would use b.id  and without this
__BILL_ID__ as bill_id,
just bill_price_sum.

give me a mysql_fiddle with soem data and i can write it for ya